# Why doesnt my program print the data it receives instead of the address?

Tags: java, arrays, output, tostring

I have created a java program with two classes. One class(Main) contains the array of data that is passed into the second class(Planning). The second class(Planning) uses this array to assign values to its variables 'input and output'. The code looks like this:

```
////Main.java///
import java.util.ArrayList
public class Main{
public enum State{A, D, H};

Planning plan = new Planning[]{
      new Plan(new State[]{State.A,State.A,State.A,State.A}, new State[]{State.D,State.A,State.A,State.D,State.A,State.A})}
```

The other Class Planning.java looks like this:

```
public class Planning {


    Main.State[] input;
    Main.State[] output;
    Planning(Main.State[] input,Main.State[] output){
    this.input = input;
    this.output = output;

    System.out.println("The state is " + input);
}
```

However when I printout the 'input at the end' it displays

> [LMain$State;@4e98f805

I want it to display the array that is passed into it from the main function. Could someone kindly tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: You are printing the memory address. Loop over the elements in the array and print out each element individually.

Comment: Use a loop to iterate over the array and print individual values............................   for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {System.out.println(input[i]+" ")}

Comment: SO is not shortcut for learning basic stuff. You should at least read up about basics of language before asking trivial questions.

Comment: @user3360241 I do not agree (completely), as far as the question shows a minimal research effort and is clear. "Trivial" is a subjective word.

Comment: @user3360241: I am sorry to have offende you by my 'TRIVIAL' question.  I am a very new Java programmer and still getting to know more about it. I have had a background of C and it takes time to get used to a new language. For you it might be trivial but for me it was a huge problem .But thanks anyway for ur input :)

Comment: @digidude :Thank you for that tip :)

Comment: my pleasure @Goldengirl  :)

Comment: I would define minimal research effort as effort spent on resolving the issue, not effort spent on creating the one. I guess we could say that there was an effort in creating the question, but can you honestly state that there was any effort invested into solving it? @Goldengirl there are arrays in C also, so the term is familiar to you. Minimal research effort imho would be typing into google java + arrays, first 1000 results would most likely give you enough information to resolve the question on your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe Try to use `System.out.println("The state is " + Arrays.toString(input));`

Because printing input is equivalent to printing input.toString(); and this print the memory address of the array.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 2):

You could override the `toString()` method in your `Planning` class, so when you print out a `Planning` object it will print the information you want it to.

Something like

```
public class Planning {
        Main.State[] input;
        Main.State[] output;

        Planning(Main.State[] input,Main.State[] output) {
            this.input = input;
            this.output = output;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { 
            return "PRINT INFORMATION FROM THE INPUT HERE THUS THE LOGIC FOR PRINTING THE INFO IS ENCAPSULATED";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To print just a small change in your Planning class :

```
 public class Planning {


        Main.State[] input;
        Main.State[] output;
        Planning(Main.State[] input,Main.State[] output){
            this.input = input;
            this.output = output;

            for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
                System.out.println("The state is " + input[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share why down voted for it? This is one of the way to achieve it

Comment: It will print `The state is ` many times (`input.length` times, exactly). And the whole `for` loop can be eliminated by using `Arrays.asList(input)` or `Arrays.toString(input)`, as suggested in another answer.

Comment: @Roman That is true but it will serve the purpose. I never said it is perfect but it serves the purpose. And if you don't want to print it several times then you can first append to String ad then print it the way you want. And if you will see the Arrays.toString(input) will also have the same implementation.